# Integration Techniques and forms

Tags: integration, trigonometry, substitution

Integrate; $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}} \, dx $$

I can get the answer by substituting $\sec t = \dfrac{x}{a}$ but I am left with $\ln\left|\dfrac{x + \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a}\right|$. Granted, this is right but how would I get there without having the 1/a in the log?

Also is there a way to find $\int \sec t \space dt$ without having to multiply by $\dfrac{\sec t + \tan t}{\sec t + \tan t}$?

and finally, more of a general question; are there and integrals in which only a hyperbolic substitution can be used to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding $\int\sec x\,dx$, you can do a tangent half-angle substitution, that is:
$t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ and thus $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: @cheesyfluff: Thanks for the editing.

Comment: Really good answer

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the log of a quotient is equal to the log of the numerator minus the log of the denominator: $\ln\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \ln f(x) - \ln g(x)$
Therefore the $1/a$ is absorbed into the constant from the indefinite integral.

The method you have given for finding $\int \sec{t} \space dt$ is the simplest method I know of, but there is another way using sin and cos substitutions shown here: [Find the integration of $\sec(x)$ and prove it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506780/find-the-integration-of-secx-and-prove-it)

See this answer regarding hyperbolics:
[Are there integrals you can't solve without inverse hyperbolic substitution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759666/are-there-integrals-you-cant-solve-without-inverse-hyperbolic-substitution)